# MATLAB: Take a double array and produce a rounded cell array of strings

Tags: matlab

I've got a 11x7 double array A.

I want to round those numbers to 2 decimal places (I don't care if some minor rounding errors are introduced), and then create an 11x7 cell array of strings.

`CellArray = arrayfun(@num2str, A, 'unif', 0)` does the job of creating the cell array, but I understand that by the time I've converted the double array to a string array it's too late to do the rounding.

So I tried `CellArray = strtrim(cellstr(num2str(A,'%.2f')))`.

This creates a cell array of strings, and the rounding is appropriate. However, it's 11x1, and not 11x7, which is what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@(A)(num2str(A,'%.2f')` instead of `@num2str` to have a anonymous function which converts to sting using the format you want.

```
CellArray = arrayfun(@(A)(num2str(A,'%.2f')), A, 'unif', 0)
```